# What steps should I follow to deploy a .rdlc report that uses ReportViewer control into server

Tags: reportviewer

I am trying to deploy a .rdlc report that uses ReportViewer control in a web application into server.

Everything works fine in my local machine using Visual Studio Development Server, but I get 500 error in the server. Any standard steps to follow for deployment of .rdlc reports? I am using IIS 7.5.

Answer (score 1):

you must install the redistribuatble onto your server

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6442